# From definition of Cauchy sequence to definition of limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then $$\lvert a_n-a_m\rvert<\varepsilon\quad\forall n,m >N_0$$

> *Question.* Why we have that  $$\lvert a_n-\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m\rvert\le \varepsilon\quad \forall n>N_0\tag 1$$

I know that limits do not preserve strong inequalities. I don't understand how to get $(1)$ formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because
\begin{align}
  \left|a_n-\lim_{m\to\infty}a_m\right|&=\left|\lim_{m\to\infty}(a_n-a_m)\right|\\
  &=\lim_{m\to\infty}|a_n-a_m|\\
  &\le\varepsilon
\end{align}
since, when $m\geqslant N_0$, $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon.$